# List all non-deprecated images in a project returning empty list with filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-developers-console

I am trying to fetch the all non-deprecated images by applying filter but I am getting blank list as images List.
I have tried through same code as given in documentation  as well as GCP Api explorer.

Documentation link:https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/samples/compute-images-list#compute_images_list-java

API explorer link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/list

GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images

E.g. for filters:
"deprecated.state != DEPRECATED" - blank list, "deprecated.state != false", "deprecated = null" etc. all combinations.

Anyone have idea for correct filter.

Comment: It's confusing. I think you can `NOT deprecated:*`. `deprecated:*` is `has property "deprecated"` and the `NOT` negates it.

Comment: I want to retrieve only those images which are not deprecated.  What I want to something like this.  `code`         try (ImagesClient imagesClient = ImagesClient.create(imagesSettings)) {
            ListImagesRequest imagesRequest = ListImagesRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setProject(imagePublisher)
                              .setFilter("deprecated.state != DEPRECATED")
                    .build();
            ImagesClient.ListPagedResponse images = imagesClient.list(imagesRequest);
            images.iterateAll().forEach(imageList::add);

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for response :  I am iterating at client side each image to check hasDeprecated or not. But I don't want to iterate as it will impact performance. I just want retrieve required images so that list will be shorter. Just like above comment `code` {
            ImagesClient.ListPagedResponse images = imagesClient.list(imagePublisher);
            images.iterateAll().forEach(image -> {
                if (!image.hasDeprecated()) {
                    imageList.add(image);
                }
            });
        }